# How to like / share URLs inside Facebook that contain get-parameters

Tags: facebook

We are working on a facebook-app with lots of dynamic pages. As the app is embedded in a tab on a facebook page, the urls contain a get-parameter to address the correct tab/app. We want to implement like- and send-buttons for several pages within our app, but facebook seems to dump all get-parameters from urls within facebook. As the result all like- and send-buttons point to the facebook-page itself instead of the tab.

Does anybody now any workaround? We already tried redirects via an external sefor facebook urls only.rver but facebook seems to evaluate the links on click of the like-/send-button (and seems to follow all sort of redirects).

**UPDATE:**
Here is an example of a problematic url:
https://www.facebook.com/smartmobil.de?sk=app_171502639574871

**UPDATE:**
The problem seems to be independant of url get-parameters. It seems that the like-button does not work with any url starting with www.facebook.com

When used in a like-button everything behind the ? will be dumped. This seems to happen for facebook urls only.

Comment: Can you post the code of one of your like buttons?  I'm using a get parameter in a like button on a project that's working in so much as the parameter passes, but it creates a page for every separate like.

Comment: I updated my post with an example url. It works for urls outside of facebook (like youtube videos).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best workaround so far is to point your like buttons at external (non-facebook canvas) urls.

To make this work, you need to do some conditional redirecting to get the user back into your canvas URL. You can either use a client side javascript redirect:

```
<script>
  window.location = 'http://apps.facebook.com/yourcanvasname/foo/bar';
</script>
```

Or you can do a server side redirect based on the useragent string. Basically, if the useragent contains 'facebookexternalhit' then render a basic HTML page containing OG tags, if not, redirect to the canvas URL.

Doing this means the Facebook sharescraper/linter won't follow any redirects back to the canvas URL, but any user that arrives at your URL *will* get back to Canvas.

Comment: That is our plan b. It is error-prone as it is user agent dependent and facebook might change its user agent or link scraping mechanism at any time. I believe it is against the facebook tos aswell.

Answer (score 1):

i'm too searching for a solution to control the custom page tab's content through a get parameter (app_data). I still don't have a solution but here at least the reason why all www.facebook.com links are srtiped out of get params. [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397/) at bottom the developer explains why.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.  Posting a like programmatically requires you to specify a Facebook content ID or alias.  This won't work for you because tabs to not seem to have an exposed content ID of their own, and instead use the Page's content ID with an additional parameter which you can't use with the graph.

Liking external links and other content that does not have an ID programmatically is prohibited.  With an external URL, the first like of an unrecognised URL creates a new Facebook page for those likes to be represented on (which is the issue I've given up trying to fight), but presumably the presence of your Page's content ID alias (www.facebook.com/smartmobil.de) in the url is making Facebook choose you page rather than creating a new one.

The only suggestion I can think of this late at night is to target an external URL that performs a redirect via Javascript, rather than on the server, but Facebook may be wise to that too and I'm afraid I'm going to bed rather than testing it :)

Comment: We do not want to like programmatically but thru the standard like-buttons. And like-buttons seem to work fine with e.g. YoutTube urls which contain a get parameter that identifies the video. Facebook seems to catch even js-redirects, we tested that aswell.

Comment: I have an app that uses the iframe like button and don't eat the get parameters, but it's using an `apps.facebook.com` url instead of `www.facebook.com`.

Comment: Our app runs in a tab embedded in a facebook page so we can not use the apps... base url.

Comment: Hmm...then you may be screwed :)  Have you tried using a hash fragment instead of GET parameters?

Comment: I updated my question. The problem lies in the base-url of www.facebook.com. No like-buttons seem to work here as the linter-tool confirms.